# how to find static files with same path and same name in Django?

Tags: python, django

Now, I have a Django web site which has two projects. One is root project and another is a app.

The directory structure is below:

**--root project

   --static

      --templates

         --index.html

--app

   --static

      --templates

         --index.html**

The relative settings in setting.py is below:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8')).replace('\\', '/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

And, when I want to specify a path to "/app/static/templates/index.html", I always get index.html in root.If I change the turn in STATICFILES_FINDERS, I will face the same problem when I want to get index.html in root.

How can I accurately get one of them?

Comment: are these templates django templates? or templates for some client side js library?

Comment: @andrean All are Django templates. I want each template is attached to each app(easy to find for editing), so I put app templates in app's sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your directory structure seems strange...

First thing, in case the `index.html` in the app directory is supposed to be a Django-template, it shouldn't be under the static directory.

Also, you mentioned that you used the path `/app/static/templates/index.html`, which actually shouldn't work at all.

Usually in Django, the `/static/` path will be used to access static resources from all apps' static directories, as well as all directories specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, **as if all the content from all those directories is "merged" into one `/static/` directory!**

So, in your example, the path `/static/templates/index.html` indeed refers to both the `index.html` from the root project directory, as well as the `index.html` from the app-specific static directory, which is why the actual file you get will depend on the order of static files finders specified.

The recommended layout to avoid such collisions would be:

```
-project root
 -static
  -global static resources accessible via /static/...
 -app
  -static
   -app
    -app-specific static resources accessible via /static/app/...
```

This is also appropriate for app-template directories:

```
 -app1
  -templates
   -app1
    -index.html (referred from Django view as 'app1/index.html')
 -app2
  -templates
   -app2
    -index.html (referred from Django view as 'app2/index.html')
```

*Edit to add info on shared templates:*

If you're trying to have a "base-template" that is extended by other apps, I would recommend using the "common-app" approach.
You simply create a new app (named e.g. "common", although you can name it however you want), that contains common templates (and other logic, if you'd like), and have the app-specific templates extend it.

The layout would be:

```
 -app1
  -templates
   -app1
    -index.html
 -common
  -templates
   -common
    -base.html
```

And in `index.html` you'll have `{% extends "common/base.html" %}` at the top of the file (read the [Django docs on template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) if you're unfamiliar with it).

Of course, the `common` app must be enabled in the Django settings for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!

The reason why my directory structure seems like this is that I want each template is attached to its relative app(I think it is easy to find for editing).

And last, What is the usual structure in Django if I have some templates(such as homepage.html) in main project and some in app?

Comment: I edited the original answer to cover the part on base template that can be extended by app-templates.